# Escaping "@" in Roxygen2 Style Documentation

Tags: r, roxygen

Let's say I have a comment block where I'd like to write an email address. How would I go about escaping the "@" symbol so roxygen treats it as text instead of a directive?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A double at-sign `@@` will do the job.

As an example, take the email address in the author field of this documentation:

```
##' A package to check Roxygen's sanity.
##' @name helloRoxygen-package
##' @docType package
##' @author My name \email{me@@here.org}
NA
```

which produces this `*.Rd` file when processed with `roxygenize()`:

```
\docType{package}
\name{helloRoxygen-package}
\alias{helloRoxygen-package}
\title{A package to check Roxygen's sanity.}
\description{
  A package to check Roxygen's sanity.
}
\author{
  My name \email{me@here.org}
}
```

Comment: Be nice to note here how @ symbols handled when accessing slots in @example code.

Comment: @tim -- How are they handled? Do they require special treatment, or have the roxygen authors just allowed example code to be passed along verbatim?