# Using a @ sign with roxygen2

Tags: r, roxygen, roxygen2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Escaping “@” in Roxygen2 Style Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809004/escaping-in-roxygen2-style-documentation)

How can I use @ in roxygen documentation as in:

```
#' @param arg An argument that uses the symbol @
```

This will throw up an warning when you run `roxygenize` and not put the @ in the .Rd fle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can escape it with another @

```
#' @param arg An argument that uses the symbol @@
```

Comment: I meant to answer my own question but you were so quick you beat me to it.  I'm going to delete my own solution as it's redundant.  +1 for correctness and speed.

Comment: @TylerRinker, :)  I think there is a checkbox to answer your own question before you post it.

Comment: @TylerRinker Also see this identical SO question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809004/escaping-in-roxygen2-style-documentation/8809391#8809391 .  I often wish their search algorithm was better at turning up related questions.